# AS3 Events and passing parameters

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to pass parameters when an event is triggered. My function:

```
private function keyChange(e:KeyboardEvent, setValue:Boolean):void
```

so that I can use the same function to set if a key is up or down. How would I write the event listener? I tried:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyChange(,true));
```

however that didn't work. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyChangeHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyChangeHandler);

...

private function keyChangeHandler(e:KeyBoardEvent):void
{
    var keyDown:Boolean = e.type == KeyBoardEvent.KEY_DOWN;

    ...
    // Do stuff
}
```

However if you want to pass parameters, you need to use a custom event:

```
public class KeyBoardActionEvent extends KeyBoardEvent
{
    public var shouldSetValue:Boolean;
    public function KeyBoardActionEvent(setValue:Boolean, type:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false):void
    {
        shouldSetValue = setValue;
        super(type, bubbles, cancleable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward way is to examine the events inside your event handler.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyChange);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyChange);

private function keyChange(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    if (e.type == KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN) {
         // ... handle key down, etc...
    }
}
```

You could also do it by passing `addEventListener` an inline function that passes the parameter you want, or maybe do something tricky with closures, but it wouldn't gain you anything over the above way.

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to find your solution,

```
 stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,function(e:MouseEvent):void{keyChange(e,true)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally possible. Easy and simple:

```
private function keyChange(setValue:Boolean):Function {
  return function(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    // Now you have both "e" and "setValue" here
  }
}
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyChange(true));
```

What if you want to remove the listener later? Just take `keyChange()` out:

```
var functionKeyChange:Function = keyChange(true);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, functionKeyChange);
stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, functionKeyChange);
```

If you find this solution interesting, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13488640).